# Can I re-apply some commit to ANOTHER file?

Tags: git

Given we have some commit which modifies some files.

We have other versions of these files stored in some other folder.

current version:

```
/ver.1.0/someFile.txt
```

old version:

```
/ver.2.0/someFile.txt
```

I have made some modifications in ver.1.0 file and committed them. But I have forgotten to make this modification in 2.0 version. **Is it possible to solve this problem without manual copy-pasting, just like applying cherry-pick?**

I cannot just copy the file from 1.0 to 2.0 because some other parts of file may differ.

Comment: No. A commit is a snapshot of the workingdir(in your example of the file) for this particular moment. ver.2.0. is a complete different file for git then ver.1.0/somefile

Comment: Its a pity! May be I can create some diff and apply it somehow?

Comment: This is possible. You create a diff with *git format-patch* and apply it with a typical *nix *patch* command.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use a patch file and apply to the other one. A commit in itself represents work done on specific files in a specific branch, but what you want is the same changes in two places so a patch is what you want

Comment: @ckruczek, you can also use `git-apply` to apply created patch if you adjust it a bit (change paths to file).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using git incorrectly. Instead of having two folders `/ver.1.0/someFile.txt` and `/ver.2.0/someFile.txt` you should in fact only have one file `/someFile.txt` and then use git branches to distinguish between `ver.1.0` and `ver.2.0`.

However in your case you can bodge it by doing a `git diff` (which generates a list of differences) and saving it to a file. You can then edit the paths referred to in the file to point to the other one. This will then re-apply the same delta to the different path.